# how to set button on the bottom and also on the center ? - android

Tags: android

How can i set the Button on the android XML on the bottom of linear layout and also at the center of the bottom ?
Thanks in advance !

```
<Button
  android:layout_gravity="center"
       />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using relative layout...

you can do something like this

If you have a relative layout that fills the whole screen you should be able to use `android:layout_alignParentBottom` to move your view to the bottom of the screen.

then set `layout_marginleft` to your desired value to set it to center

Answer (score 0):

See if it is what are looking for :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```